# How to retrieve the cloud foundry oauth token from a devops deploy stage for setting up auto scaling?

Tags: ibm-cloud, autoscaling, devops-services

I'm trying to get the cloud foundry oauth-token from a devops pipeline deploy stage:

```
...
cf push $CF_APP
...

accessToken=$(cf oauth-token | grep bearer | sed -e s/bearer/Bearer/g)
echo accessToken=$accessToken
...
# use token in Auto Scaling API call ...
curl $createPolicyUrl -X 'PUT' -H 'Content-Type:application/json' \
     -H 'Accept:application/json' \
     -H "Authorization:$accessToken" \
     --data-binary @${policyJson} \
     -s -o response.txt -w '%{http_code}\n'
```

The output from the echo command is:

```
accessToken=
```

How can I retrieve the oauth token?

Note that `cf push` works ok in the script ecen though there isn't a `cf login` performed in the deploy script.  Therefore, I'm assuming cf oauth-token would not need login either.  Is this a valid assumption?

Update: I added `cf login` to my deploy script:

```
...
cf push $CF_APP
...

cf login
accessToken=$(cf oauth-token | grep bearer | sed -e s/bearer/Bearer/g)
echo accessToken=$accessToken
...
```

The output:

```
cf login not allowed.
```

See also my [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44667141/how-to-programatically-reconfigure-availability-monitoring-in-devops-stage-for-b) on reconfiguring availability monitoring in a devops deploy stage.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the bluemix cli? You can login via `bx login` and then run `bx cf oauth-token`. I think that should get you what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to do a `cf login` to log in before you run the `cf oauth-token` command. Also make sure to double quote `"Authorization:$accessToken"` so the variable is substituted.

Update: It looks like you can access the oauth-token from within the script via the `$CF_TOKEN` environment variable. The token is associated with the owner of the pipeline, not the user running the current pipeline stage.

Comment: Unfortunately, `cf login` is not allowed.  I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Yes, in Delivery Pipeline it's best to use the `$CF_TOKEN`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
accessToken=$(cf oauth-token)
CF_TOKEN=$(echo $accessToken | grep “Bearer*” | perl -wpe ‘s/.*(Bearer .+)/$1/‘)
CF_TOKEN should now have the token value
```